# Как заставить объект вести себя как дочерний, не делая его таковым?

Tags: unity3d

Я пробую перемещать объект B относительно объекта А так, как если бы объект В был дочерним по отношению к А. Получается не совсем корректно.

В чём глобальная задача? Я поднимаю VR-контроллером объект со стола (например, гайку) и перемещаю его по сцене. Звучит просто. В сцене есть `GameObject _cursor`, позицию и поворот которого я получаю от устройства ввода (VR-контроллер). С помощью `Physics.OverlapSphere` нахожу коллайдер объекта, который хочу переместить.

И решение «в лоб» состоит в том, чтобы сделать перемещаемый объект дочерним по отношению к `_cursor`. В ассетах Oculus для Unity как раз реализован подобный способ. Проблема в том, что перемещаемый объект должен взаимодействовать с другими объектами сцены - не пролетать сквозь стол и другие объекты. Т. е. в нем должен быть включен коллайдер. Проблема в том, что такой объект сносит абсолютно все другие незамороженные объекты сцены, имеющие коллайдер и `Rigidbody`. От этого хотелось избавиться.

Решение следующее - перемещать объект с помощью `Rigidbody.MovePosition`, предварительно задав ему достаточно маленькую массу. Но как определить, куда его нужно переместить? Ведь я не хочу `transform` перемещаемого объекта «притягивать» к `_cursor`. Изначально на ум пришло использование «прокси» - пустого `GameObject`, дочернего к `_cursor`. При «хватании» этот прокси-объект принимал значение `transform.position` от схваченного объекта. И в дальнейшем перемещаемый объект методом `Rigidbody.MovePosition` перемещался в позицию прокси объекта. И в принципе, это работает. Но хочется избавиться от дополнительного объекта-пустышки.

Решение следующее. При «хватании» получить вектор от `transform` схваченного объекта до `transform` объекта `_cursor`:

```
Vector3 direction = _target.transform.position - _cursor.transform.position;
```

а также

```
Quaternion _oldRotation = _cursor.transform.rotation;
```

При обновлении кадра делаю следующее:

```
private void Update()
{
    /* Здесь получаем вращение _cursor относительно предыдущего кадра */
    Quaternion _difRotation = Quaternion.Inverse(_oldRotation) * _cursor.transform.rotation;

    _oldRotation = _cursor.transform.rotation;

    /* Здесь поворачиваем вектор кватернионом */
    direction = _difRotation * direction;

    /* 
    * Здесь перемещаем объект с учетом позиции _cursor в пространстве сцены 
    * и повернутого вектора direction.
    * Для упрощения не используем Rigidbody.MovePosition
    */
    _target.position = _cursor.transform.position + direction;
}
```

Результат выглядит правдоподобно, но есть «нюансы». Для наглядности я собрал упрощенную сцену, использующую такой подход. Здесь `ref` выступает в роли `_cursor`, а `base` - перемещаемый объект. Объект `sub` - дочерний к `base` и нужен для большей наглядности проблемы. А проблема в том, что пока `ref` вращается вокруг осей (x, y, z), всё выглядит идеально.

[image: Исходное состояние]
[image: Вращение вокруг осей]

Но стоит сделать произвольный поворот, как всё ломается. Что странно, ведь я использую кватернион, который не должен зависеть от вращения через углы Эйлера.

[image: Всё сломалось]
[image: Всё сломалось]

[Видео](https://youtu.be/PKo-wQ3o46Q)

Что я делаю не так? И как ещё можно решить вопрос, вынесенный в заголовок?

Comment: Поскольку руки проходят сквозь объекты, а взятый предмет нет (должен упираться), логично, что он должен висеть на `joint`ах... И неужели в интернетах нет ни одного туториала на эту тему по `Unity3d`. Вот прям не верю.

Comment: О `joint` думал. Скажу больше - это был один из первых опробованных вариантов. С ним были проблемы. По прошествии полугода уже точно не вспомню, какие именно, но мы решили его не использовать. Да и хотелось бы с векторами разобраться. Вроде бы векторная алгебра - это чуть ли не школьный материал. Вроде бы просто, но есть какой-то непонятный подвох.

Comment: Это же `joint`, их дохрена разных с уймой настроек и ими мало кто пользуется, поэтому и проблемы, но это не значит что их нужно менять на другие проблемы.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Вариант с `joint` вполне может быть применим. Мы от него отказались не из-за его неработоспособности. Но хотелось бы доразобраться с векторами и кватернионами. К тому же, объект в определенный момент начинает взаимодействовать с другим объектом (напр. гайка должна быть навинчена на шпильку). В этой ситуации нужно иметь контроль над перемещением и вращением. Например, ограничить передвижение вдоль оси шпильки, которая может быть задана произвольным вектором. Думаю, с джойнами возникнут свои трудности, от которых я в основном избавился, используя, MovePosition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка кроется здесь:

```
Quaternion _difRotation = Quaternion.Inverse(_oldRotation) * _cursor.transform.rotation;
```

Рассмотрим пример:

```
new = q * old
```

где new - кватернион в новом кадре, old - в старом, а q - вращение между кадрами.

```
new = q * old,
```

домножим обе части на Inverse(old) справа, то есть на обратную матрицу old

```
new * Inverse(old) = q * old * Inverse(old)
```

далее учитывая что `old * Inverse(old)` это единичная матрица, и на то, что мы вправе поставить скобки так:

```
new * Inverse(old) = q * (old * Inverse(old))
```

опираясь на ассоциативность кватернионов

```
new * Inverse(old) = q;

q = new * Inverse(old);
```

Таким образом получаем:

```
Quaternion _difRotation = _cursor.transform.rotation * Quaternion.Inverse(_oldRotation);
```

Учитывая некоммутативность произведения кватернионов, логичночто вы получили другой результат.

И в приведенном вами куске кода не увидел, где меняется rotation у _target (видимо где-то в другом месте).

Вот на всякий случай код, который работает:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotator : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform _target;
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform _cursor;
    private Quaternion _oldRotation;
    private Vector3 direction;

    private void Update()
    {
        direction = _target.transform.position - _cursor.transform.position;

        /* Здесь получаем вращение _cursor относительно предыдущего кадра */
        Quaternion _difRotation = _cursor.transform.rotation * Quaternion.Inverse(_oldRotation); // 1

        _oldRotation = _cursor.transform.rotation;

        /* Здесь поворачиваем вектор кватернионом */
        direction = _difRotation * direction;

        /* 
        * Здесь перемещаем объект с учетом позиции _cursor в пространстве сцены 
        * и повернутого вектора direction.
        * Для упрощения не используем Rigidbody.MovePosition
        */
        _target.position = _cursor.transform.position + direction;
        _target.rotation = _difRotation * _target.rotation; // 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Оказывается, математика не только ум в порядок приводит, но и помогает найти глупые ошибки.